# Determine if a set of nodes in a graph is a cluster

Tags: algorithm, graph, set, graph-algorithm

If I have a grid-like graph and a set of nodes like [A,B,J,K].

```
Grid Graph:

A B C D
E F G H
I J K L

Note: diagonals not considered neighbours
```

What is the best way to check if those nodes are all adjacent AND form a cluster?

In the example above, [A,B] are adjacent and [J,K] are adjacent but as a whole, the set does not form a cluster. If 'F' was added to the set to form [A,B,F,J,K], then I would consider it a cluster.

**Updated:** I already have a function that checks if two nodes are adjacent boolean isAdjacent(Node a, Node b). Just need to expand on it to check for the cluster.

Comment: What do you mean by "cluster?"

Comment: By cluster, I mean a group of nodes that have a PATH from one node in the cluster to every other node in the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your original graph be `G = (V,E)` and `SET` the desired set of node ( `SET <= V` )

Create a graph `G' = (V',E')` where `V' = SET` and `E' = { (u,v) | (u,v) is in E and u,v is in SET }`

If the graph `G'` is connected you have a cluster of all elements.

The maximal cluster is the maximal connected component in `G'`.

finding the maximal connected component can be done with something like [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

(**Note**, using the flood fill in the first place with a restriction, can modulate the graph creation of `G'` without the need to actually build it).

pseudo code, using [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find clusters:

```
int maximalCluster(E,SET): //SET is the set of desired nodes, E is the edges in G.
    roots <- new map<node,interger>
    for each node n in SET: 
       //run a BFS for each root, 
       //and count the total number of elements reachable from it
       queue <- { n } 
       roots.put(n,1)
       while (queue is not empty):
           curr <- queue.takeFirst()
           for each edge (curr,u) in E:
              if (u is in SET):
                  SET.delete(u)
                  queue.add(u)
                  roots.put(roots.get(n) + 1)
    return max { roots.get(v) | for each  v in roots.keys }
```

Though the pseudo code above doesn't generate `G'`, it simulates it by checking only edges that their nodes are in SET.

Comment: I eventually did a modified version of BFS to mark the visited nodes. If there were any nodes left unvisited, then they were on an unreachable cluster. BFS was what I needed. Thanks.